# How to obtain a copied image from the pasteboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, copy-paste, uipasteboard

I have a photo editing app where I want to provide a way for the user to edit photos from the pasteboard. For example the user might copy a photo from his website in Safari and then head over to my app and choose "Open from pasteboard". Kind of like Photoshop does it.

How can I get notified or check if there is a picture or graphic (probably a UIImage) in the pasteboard? And how could I obtain that image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed one for a UIImage and [this](http://flikode.com/snip/2010/01/12/144102/pasteboard---iphone-get-images-in-clipboard) snippet helped me out.

You can always extract the image out using:

```
UIImage *image = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].image;
```

Comment: Looks great, but unfortunately images copied in Safari won't show up there under all circumstances... at least not in the simulator. On the device it seems to work fine though!